# How much money does the Christian Church save because of religious tax exemption in the United States?

Tags: money

The only source I have been able to find is [85 billion dollars](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/wonk/wp/2013/08/22/you-give-religions-more-than-82-5-billion-a-year/) but that's all religions. How much does Christianity, specifically, save because of religious tax exemption?

Comment: About 12% of the total due to taxes in Canada!

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394). A better question would be how much does everyone else lose. You don't "save" money by not being taxed. You just keep what belongs to you. Everyone who *is* taxed *loses* money.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Much, much less than that, if anything.**

The $85billion figure has already been debunked in [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/19693/if-american-churches-paid-taxes-how-much-revenue-would-that-generate).

Religious institutions would not pay $85b even if they were taxed as profit-making businesses. $85B would be around 3/4 of the entire amount of money donated to all religious organizations in the US. No entity pays 75% of its income in taxes - nor would it exist if it was taxed at that rate.